# Unable to attach Event Listener to react-bootstrap modal for mouse events using ref

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

Unable to attach Event Listener to react-bootstrap modal for mouse events using ref

Getting TypeError: Modal.addEventListener is not a function while trying to attach event listener

Error message:

[image]

Below is sample code:

```
import React, { useRef,useState,useEffect } from "react";
import {Button,Modal} from 'react-bootstrap';


function ExampleModal() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    const cardRef = useRef(null);

   useEffect(()=>{
    const Modal = cardRef?.current;
    // ****TypeError: Modal.addEventListener is not a function*****
    Modal?.addEventListener("mousedown",mousedownhandler );
    return () => {

      // unsubscribe event
      Modal?.removeEventListener("mousedown", mousedownhandler);
    }}
   ,[])

  const mousedownhandler=()=>{console.log('mousedown on modal')}

    return (
      <>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
          Launch demo modal
        </Button>
  
        <Modal ref={cardRef} show={show} onHide={handleClose} >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
              Close
            </Button>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
              Save Changes
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </>
    );
  }
  
  export default ExampleModal;
```

Comment: Alerting seems an over-simplified result of mousing down in the modal, what are you really trying to attach a ref to the modal component for?

Comment: I am trying to get reference of modal element and pass it to other component where i can attach event listeners to passed modal reference so that i can implement dragging functionality of any passed modal reference. could you please help me out